# mongodb check an element has one nested attribute

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents like this

```
[
{ "name": "pika", "attrs": { "A": 1, "B": 2 ...  } },
{ "name": "chu", "attrs": { "C": 3 } },
{ "name": "plop", "attrs": { "A": 1, "C": 3 } }
]
```

I would like to delete records that have a "C" and only a "C" attribute in their "attrs"  (line named "chu") using mongodb 2.4. The number of possible attributes under the attrs key is possibly large (> 100).

I can use several queries.

How would you do that ?

Edit : I want to keep attr C in lines containing other attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.  If your key space is small you can do

```
db.collection.remove( {C : {$exists:true}, A: {$exists:false}, B: {$exists: false} })
```

Otherwise you'll need to do

```
var col = db.collection.find( {C : {$exists:true}} );
for(doc in col) {
    var found = false
    for(key in obj) {
        if( key !== 'C' ) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found === false) {
        db.collection.remove(doc);
    }
}
```

There's no way to count the number of keys in a document directly within MongoDB and there's no way to query on wildcards in key names (e.g. you can't do "key not equal to C : {$exists: false}").  So you either need to test all keys explicitly or test each document in your application layer.

Comment: I should have mentioned I can have X different keys, X being large. I am going to edit the question with that. However, both solutions you gave are interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If the "attrs" is a array,  in other words, you collections like this:

```
{ "name": "pika", "attrs": [{ "A": 1}, {"B": 2}] };
{ "name": "chu", "attrs": [{ "C": 3 }] };
{ "name": "plop", "attrs": [{ "A": 1}, {"C": 3 }] }
```

Then you can write a query like below to find the specific record you want:

```
db.entities.find({"attrs.C": {$exists: true}, "attrs": {$size: 1}});
```

You can check the mongodb website to find the $size operation, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/size/

Comment: I did not know the "$size" operator. You answer is great unfortunately, attrs is not an array.